# Most efficient way to populate/distribute indexedDB [datastore] with 350000 records

Tags: javascript, performance, indexeddb, ydn-db

So, I have a main indexedDB objectstore with around 30.000 records on which I have to run full text search queries. Doing this with the ydn fts plugin this generates a second objectstore with around 300.000 records. Now, as generating this 'index' datastore takes quite long I figured it had be faster to distribute the content of the index as well. This in turn generated a zip file of around 7MB which after decompressing on the client side gives more than 40MB of data. Currently I loop over this data inserting it one by one (async, so callback time is used to parse next lines) which takes around 20 minutes. As I am doing this in the background of my application through a webworker this is not entirely unacceptable, but still feels hugely inefficient. Once it has been populated the database is actually fast enough to be even used on mid to high end mobile devices, however the population time of 20 minutes to one hour on mobile devices is just crazy. Any suggestions how this could be improved? Or is the only option minimizing the number of records? (which would mean writing my own full text search... not something I would look forward to)

Answer (score 1):

Your data size is quite large for mobile browser. Unless user constantly using your app, it is not worth sending all data to client. You should use server side for full text search, while catching opportunistically as illustrated by [this example app](http://dev.yathit.com/demo/ydn-db-text/pubmed-search/index.html). In this way, user don't have to wait for full text search indexing.

Full-text search require to index all tokens (words) except some stemming words. Stemming is activated only when `lang` is set to `en`. You should profile your app which parts is taking time. I guess browser is taking most of the time, in that case, you cannot do much optimization other than parallelization. Sending indexed data (as you described above) will not help much (but please confirm by comparing). Also Web worker will not help. I assume your app have no problem with slow respond due to indexing.

Do you have other complaint other than slow indexing time?

Comment: Yeah, only problem was the slow indexing time, ended up building my own full text search which brought the record count down significantly and now runs beautifully :D