# Syncing IndexedDB with Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, indexeddb

I am doing offline DB connectivity in my page using HTML5 IndexedDB concepts.. But Initially, I want to fetch large datas to store it in my IndexedDb, so for that purpose, I am trying to sync Sql Server Data to my IndexedDb Datatbase but I didnt find any solution to do that.. Is there any way to do that, If so Pls help me.. thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand in your question, you are just using indexeddb like a cache layer in case the db goes done. What I would do is the following.

In case you are working online a save of your data should exist out af 2 actions. Saving to your service (SQL server) and save to your indexeddb.

In case when you are offline I would do 2 operation. On is still updating your indexeddb, but I would add an extra object store where you save all of your operation that have to be preformed on your service. Once back online, you can processes them one by one.

Comment: I am using IndexedDB to populate first time from SQL Server and save it in my indexedDB... Datas in my SQL Server wont be changing repeatedly, it ll be almost same or maybe rarely some changes may happen.. So, I will be almost working offline with my IndexedDB datas only.. But, I cant able to save the SQL datas to my IndexedDB.. Just for now, I have inserted some dummy datas, which is also hard coded.. I want to automate the process of copying SQL Server datas to my IndexedDB..

Comment: So the data you are saving is in the indexeddb comes directly from the SQL server and users aren't allowed to save their own? This will make it a lot easier. I think the best thing to do is expose your data from SQL server as a rest service. Next you will have to insert the data one by one, there isn't a batch insert possibility. I would advice to use one transaction for inserting your data. But for awnsering your question do you need a code sample how you can insert the data?

Comment: For Now, I have created a sample HTML file and manually inserted datas of my tables. Everything is working fine, but instead of manually inserting the datas, I want to make it more easier.

Comment: Also, I have another problem, right now, I have created a HTML file, it is working fine. But when I try to add it in my .NET project and run it, it is thrown me the error saying **"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'"**. Am I missing something, or do I need to reference something to make it work in my .NET application

Comment: On your first comment: I think the best thing to do is expose your data by using a REST service. In the .NET world you have ASP.NET MVC Web API for that. On your second comment. On which object do you get the error? The simpelest way of using the indexeddb is by using js promises. This makes the callbacks a bit easier

Comment: I am storing offline data in indexdb but I want to store that data to my remote database when the user becomes online can you please let me know how can I do that...?

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22352276/366114) and [Kristof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22355308/366114) answers, I would like to add few more things since I've worked on a similar solution.

- First of as Editor said `IndexedDB` is a document-oriented database while `SQL` is relational database which means that the you should convert your data to a object model before storing them locally
- Avoid using multiple tables in `IndexedDB` and trying to create joins.
- Additional tables in `IndexedDB` should be used if you store different objects in the database or you have additional data for your main object (example list of articles in one table - article text in the second table).

Next thing is [data synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_synchronization) - this can get really complicated if you update the data on both sides (client & server). The main problem that you'll be facing in the data synchronization is the fact that you'll have one main `SQL` database and a lot of local client databases.

Here are couple things you should also consider:

- You'll need to pick when to do the synchronization timed or by client request.
- One other question that pops up is: What if the user works a lot of the time in the offline mode and  updates an object which has been previously deleted by another user and that's stored to the `SQL` database.
- And of course when you sync the data, split it into chunks, this will reduce the size of each response and `IndexedDB` works faster with smaller transactions.
- I currently sync 500 items at a time (adjust this to the size of your objects)
- Also in `Chrome` you can access `IndexedDB` from `web-workers` and make parallel requests - this can really speed things up.

This are just some facts you'll need to consider before you start implementing the solution, hope it helps.

Comment: Great points here. Updating a store on the server side seems innocuous but has some dastardly consequences in terms of synchronization.

Comment: Hey Editor I noticed that you are following me on github and I read there that you also live in NY, I'll be speaking at the NYC HTML5 meetup next month about client storage technologies - http://www.meetup.com/html5-app-developers/events/170965392/ - join up if you can. It would be cool to meet someone else who worked with indexed db.

Comment: I've been trying to get in contact, in fact. I'll be there.

Comment: Yeah me too, I'm using the same username everywhere on the internet so write me on twitter or gmail.

Comment: I am storing offline data in indexdb but I want to store that data to my remote database when the user becomes online can you please let me know how can I do that...?

Comment: Hi Usama please take a look at the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181080/how-to-detect-online-offline-event-cross-browser

Answer (score 4):

SQL is relational database. IndexedDB is an indexed key/value store similar to a document-oriented database. There's no out of the box way to sync data from a breed of SQL to IndexedDB. You'll have to write that code manually (perhaps using [a Polyfill like this one](https://github.com/facebook/IndexedDB-polyfill/) as an example), but note that [inserting large amounts of data consecutively is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247614/optimized-bulk-chunk-upload-of-objects-into-indexeddb/22315353#22315353).

Answer (score 4):

We have implemented crud operation on HTML5 and IndexedDB database to provide offline support. The next step is to synchronize offline and online databases. In this article, we are going to implement synchronization of IndexedDB and SQL Server databases using ASP.NET Web API.

**To sync local DB from Server DB:**

```
$('#btnSyncLocal').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/service?revision=' + localStorage.customerRevision,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Revision == localStorage.customerRevision) {
                alert('You are already working on the latest version.');
            }
            else {
                syncData(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**To sync server DB from Local DB:**

```
$('#btnSyncServer').click(function () {
    var customers = [];
    db.linq.from(config.objectStoreName).select().then(function () {
        if (customers.length > 0) {
            var postData = { revision: parseInt(localStorage.customerRevision, 10), appID: config.appID, customers: customers };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api/service',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Revision == localStorage.customerRevision) {
                        alert('There is newer version on the server. Please Sync from server first.');
                    }
                    else {
                        syncData(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            alert('There is no change in data after your last synchronization.');
        }
    }, handleError, function (data) {
        if (data.Revision == -1) {
            customers.push(data);
        }
    });
});
```

For complete implementation for this example refer this link :

A sample implementation is here : 
[Syncing Offline Database (HTML5 IndexedDB) with Online Database using Asp.Net Web API](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/e717bbc3-5ca0-40e8-86a7-ba4e31c8fba8/Syncing%20Offline%20Database%20HTML5%20IndexedDB%20with%20Online%20Database%20using%20Asp%20Net%20Web%20API)

Comment: I am storing offline data in indexdb but I want to store that data to my remote database when the user becomes online can you please let me know how can I do that...?